# Does View Model get updated with Ajax call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I don't understand the following:

I have a Ajax.ActionLink on my view which initiates an ajax call to the controller, to return a partial view.
In the below View, you can see my Ajax.ActionLink methods.

Here is my View (Main Page):

```
model EDR.ViewModels.ViewModels.PersonListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Person";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="partialPlaceHolder">
            <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
            @*@using (Html.BeginForm("PersonListOptions", "Person", FormMethod.Post))*@
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PersonListOptions", "Person", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" }))
            {
                <p>
                    Search Criteria: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
                    Search Options: @Html.DropDownList("SearchOptions", ViewBag.SearchOptions as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </p>
            }
            <div id="updatedContent">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PersonListContent"); }
            </div>

            @Ajax.ActionLink("<<", "PersonListPaging", new { pageNumber = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOption = Model.SortOption }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
            @Ajax.ActionLink(">>", "PersonListPaging", new { pageNumber = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOption = Model.SortOption }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Partial View:

```
@model EDR.ViewModels.ViewModels.PersonListViewModel

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @*<th>@Html.ActionLink("Name", "PersonList", new { sort = "Name", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String })</th>*@
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Name", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "Name", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Date of Birth", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "BirthDate", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Last Reg Date", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "LastActiveRegistrationDate_NDF", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Last Reg Number", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "LastActiveRegistrationNo_NDF", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Reg Count", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "ActiveRegistrationCount_NDF", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Gender", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "GenderDescription_FKD", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var person in Model.PersonList.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@person.Name  @person.Surname</td>
                <td>@person.BirthDate</td>
                <td>@person.LastActiveRegistrationDate_Description</td>
                <td>@person.LastActiveRegistrationNo_Description</td>
                <td>@person.ActiveRegistrationCount_Description</td>
                <td>@person.Gender_Description</td>
                <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit/View", "EditPerson", "Person", new { id = person.ID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "partialPlaceHolder", HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-sm" })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my action method on my controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult PersonListPaging(int pageNumber, string sortOption)
    {
        var vm = new PersonListViewModel
        {
            PageNumber = pageNumber == 0 ? 1 : pageNumber,
            SortOption = sortOption
        };
        vm.RefreshList();
        return PartialView("_PersonListContent", vm);
    }
```

In my controller action above, I receive the page number, and then create a new VM with the currently received page number and pass it back to the view.  When I click on the button again, the same number gets passed through as previously, and the View Model has not been updated to the newly created VM in my action method. It seems like Model.PageNumber is always 1, because I keep on getting the value 2 for pageNumber in my action.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Carefully think about what you are asking.

Comment: hmm. ah, I seem to be updating my Partial View's model, but the action link is sitting on my main view, and that model's PageNumber property is being sent through, which is why I don't get an updated value...

Comment: You need to move your paging action link into partial view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your paging logic into partial view as you need to refresh page number every time when go to next or previous page.

So your main view should like this .

```
model EDR.ViewModels.ViewModels.PersonListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Person";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="partialPlaceHolder">
            <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
            @*@using (Html.BeginForm("PersonListOptions", "Person", FormMethod.Post))*@
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PersonListOptions", "Person", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" }))
            {
                <p>
                    Search Criteria: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
                    Search Options: @Html.DropDownList("SearchOptions", ViewBag.SearchOptions as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </p>
            }
            <div id="updatedContent">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PersonListContent"); }
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Partial view should be :

```
@model EDR.ViewModels.ViewModels.PersonListViewModel

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @*<th>@Html.ActionLink("Name", "PersonList", new { sort = "Name", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String })</th>*@
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Name", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "Name", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Date of Birth", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "BirthDate", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Last Reg Date", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "LastActiveRegistrationDate_NDF", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Last Reg Number", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "LastActiveRegistrationNo_NDF", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Reg Count", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "ActiveRegistrationCount_NDF", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Gender", "PersonListOptions", new { sort = "GenderDescription_FKD", sortDirection = Session["SortDirection"] as String }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" })</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var person in Model.PersonList.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@person.Name  @person.Surname</td>
                <td>@person.BirthDate</td>
                <td>@person.LastActiveRegistrationDate_Description</td>
                <td>@person.LastActiveRegistrationNo_Description</td>
                <td>@person.ActiveRegistrationCount_Description</td>
                <td>@person.Gender_Description</td>
                <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit/View", "EditPerson", "Person", new { id = person.ID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "partialPlaceHolder", HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-sm" })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@Ajax.ActionLink("<<", "PersonListPaging", new { pageNumber = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOption = Model.SortOption }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
@Ajax.ActionLink(">>", "PersonListPaging", new { pageNumber = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOption = Model.SortOption }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in my comment yes. Thanks